# Installing Delft3D on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: software-installation, compiling, 18.10

I try to install [Delft3D](https://oss.deltares.nl/web/delft3d), a modelling software on my system, but encounter some errors. The automatic installation with autogen.sh did not work so I decided to try it on my own.

I installed all needed prerequisites with apt-get and right now I try to fit the build.sh file to my system. To do so I need to know where Ubuntu installs programs loaded with apt-get. Some of them I could find in /usr/include/.
Additionally I also installed the Intel Compilers and MPI for my user under ~/usr/intel/.

Does someone already installed Delft3D on Ubuntu 18.04 or 18.10? What is the difference between MPICH2 and the MPICH which comes with apt-get?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers.

Comment: There's an active thread about this at [https://oss.deltares.nl/web/delft3d](https://oss.deltares.nl/web/delft3d) - is that you?

Comment: Also, [https://packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com) may help you - you can list the files in packages, or search for a package containing a particular file that you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. The active thread at deltares is me, that is right, but since deltares supports mainly CentOS is asked here, since I guess there are people who have a running system already.